# Java - DDPClient exception

Tags: java, android, meteor, localhost, ddp

I am trying  to connect to a running meteor application using a Java DDPClient.

I am using [this Java ddp client](https://github.com/kenyee/java-ddp-client).

I just added these couple of lines to the Android activity:

```
DDPClient mDdp = new DDPClient(sMeteorIp, sMeteorPort);
mDdp.connect();
```

but I got and exception from the `DDPClient::handleError(Exception ex)`:

```
failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 3000): connect failed:
ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

The meteor application is up and running  (version is 0.8.3, the latest for windows).
The meteor application is here: https://github.com/stefanopiovesn/ProteinTracker
The java ddp client is here: https://github.com/stefanopiovesn/DDPClient
A working ddp javascript client is here: https://github.com/stefanopiovesn/AsteroidSample
Any idea why this error happens?

Comment: I found the problem: for some reason the WebSocket library gives the `ECONNREFUSED` error when using ‘localhost’ on my Windows7 machine.<br> It works using the raw ip 192.168.1.3 and the java client can connect with the meteor server.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue. A great tool to use is ngrok! http://ngrok.com

They allow you to tunnel traffic to your local machine via a public webserver. I use it for all my development on external devices

Answer (score 0):

Well, the main reason is because when you put 'localhost', it is in relative to your application url. Not the server's url.

Your server's url is in this case your pc's raw ip as your pc is running the server on your specified port.

localhost in your android code refers to your android application instead of the localhost for server (aka your pc).

Why an exception is thrown?
- Because you don't have a server (or anything on your android application that is listening for data on your specified port) - since your code mean you are trying to connect to your own Android application from the Android application

:)